# How to define color of the text in the input of the "v-text-field" component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Is there a way to define color of the text in the input element of the "v-text-field" component?

Its "color" attribute defines just the label's color and the color of underline. But how to define the color of the text in the input element?

(Vuetify version 1.5.24)

Answer (score 2):

Try out to define a class in the `v-text-field` tag then target the inner input.

```html
<v-text-field
  class="text-field-style"
></v-text-field>
```

```html
<style scoped>
  .text-field-style >>> .v-text-field__slot input {
    color: red
  }
</style>
```

Comment: I'm looking for a dynamic way of doing this.

Comment: you can use class binding to change dynamically. `:class="{ 'text-field-style': someCondition }"`

Comment: That means you have to define as many selectors as the number of colors. But what if the color has to be calculated dynamically and the number of colors are not predefined?